# Как создать QList <QList <QImage>> SourceImageList; в котором каждый QList <QImage> был бы с определённым индексом?

Tags: c++, qt, список

Мне надо каждому QList  ImageList; присвоить определённый индекс ...Для этого я создаю `QList <QList <QImage>> SourceImageList;`
и в цикле пытаюсь добавить значения в этот список :

```
if (QueryDesk->exec("SELECT desk_id,name_desk FROM tank.desk WHERE ship_id = 3")) {
    int deskCount = 0;
    while (QueryDesk->next())
    {
      if (QueryDeckLayout->exec(QString("SELECT url,name FROM tank.deck_layout WHERE desk_id = %1").arg(QueryDesk->value(0).toString())))
      {
         int countImg=0;
         while (QueryDeckLayout->next())
         {     
            SourceImageList.at(deskCount).value(countImg,shemeImg);
            countImg++;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Но у меня возникает ошибка

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\5.11.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qlist.h, line 541
Debug Error!
```

По чему таким образом `SourceImageList.at(deskCount).value(countImg,shemeImg);` Не получается добавить значения в список и как это можно сделать ?
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
     if (QueryDesk->exec("SELECT desk_id,name_desk FROM tank.desk WHERE ship_id = 3"))
     {
            int deskCount = 0;
            while (QueryDesk->next())
            {
              if (QueryDeckLayout->exec(QString("SELECT url,name FROM tank.deck_layout WHERE desk_id = %1").arg(QueryDesk->value(0).toString())))
              {
                 int countImg=0;
                 while (QueryDeckLayout->next())
                 {     
                    QImage shemeImg;
                    shemeImg.load(FI.absoluteFilePath());
                    tempSourceImageMap.insert(countImg,shemeImg);
                    countImg++;
                  }
                 SourceImageMap.insert(tankCount,tempSourceImageMap);
               }
             deskCount++;
            }
      }
```

....
Как теперь пробежаться по значениям SourceImageMap?

```
for (int i=0;i<SourceImageMap.take(index).size();i++)
{
    SourceImageMap.take(index).take(i);
}
```

Так не выходит `SourceImageMap.take(index).size()` всегда равен 0

Comment: QList::append() - добавляет элемент в список, at() - получает уже существующий элемент из списка по его индексу/позиции в списке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать контейнер не по назначению. Списки на то и списки, чтобы обращаться с ними как со списками. В вашем же случае вам нужен ассоциативный массив, а для этого существует map - его и используйте для таких целей. Правда и там у вас не получится добавлять элементы с помощью at, так как этот метод СПЕЦИАЛЬНО создан для того, чтобы получать СУЩЕСТВУЮЩИЕ элементы, а если таковых нет - бросать исключение.

Comment: QMap<int, QMap<int, QImage>> SourceImageMap; как пробежаться по всему списку такому ?     for (int i=0;i<SourceImageMap.take(index).size();i++)
    {SourceImageMap.take(index).take(i);} Так не выходит

Comment: @IvanTriumphov а для кого итераторы? А в вашем случае и диапазонного for хватит

Comment: я переделал вопрос у меня SourceImageMap.take(index).size() всегда равен 0 ..... Как пробежаться по значениям SourceImageMap?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov вот что не понятного в слове итератор или диапазонный цикл for? Выучите наконец базовые концепции с++ и не задавайте глупых вопросов (причем дважды).

Comment: этот же форум не только для гуру программистов, но и для тех кто учиться ...... я разобрался сам спасибо

Comment: @IvanTriumphov если вы используете контейнеры с++ то, априори, вы хотябы знаете, что такое итератор. Если же вы привыкли микроскопом забивать гвозди, то таких обычно называют не "новичками" а хардкодерами, которым лень прочитать любую книгу по с++. Я не гуру, а обычный джун, который кодит на с++ один год, но даже в самом начале у меня не было привычки кривыми руками использовать то, что не знал как работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88842/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-andrej-levkovitch).